# Is there a way to remove an allied Pokémon in a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Near me, there are a couple of gyms at max level and I was wondering if there is a way to remove an allied Pokémon in those gyms and put my pokémon? Of course, without creating another account on another team, reducing prestige and then using my main account to reach the max level again.

Comment: There's no "i" in team.

Comment: ...but there is a "me".

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot remove another person's Pokemon if they are in your faction.